# How can I use a while loop to generate a delay between console logging one item and another item?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code but it doesn't seem to work. I want to log to the console "dark-green", have it wait a couple milliseconds, then log "light-green", all WITHOUT using setInterval or setTimeout. Is this possible with javascript?

```
function logGreen() {
 console.log("dark-green");
 wait(200);
 console.log("light-green");
}

function wait(ms) {
  var time = new Date();
  var milliseconds = time.getMilliseconds();
  var startTime = milliseconds;
  var currentTime = milliseconds;
  while(currentTime - startTime < ms) {
 currentTime = milliseconds;
 }
}
```

The problem I am running into is that the the loop breaks the browser so to speak, and I'm not sure how to fix this. Is there a way to do this with a for loop?

Comment: No `setInterval`? No `setTimeout`? Are you allowed to use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)?

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks the browser"?

Comment: `window.setInterval` is a much better way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that the value of currentTime is not being updated properly in your `while` loop.

The code inside your `while` loop will execute indefinitely (infinite loop) causing a stack overflow - I'm assuming that's what you mean by "breaks the browser". This is because your condition is always true:`startTime` and `currentTime` are the same value (`currentTime - startTime < 200`)

Try this instead:

```
 while(currentTime - startTime < ms) {
   time = new Date();
   currentTime = time.getTime();
 }
```

Creating a new Date object and calling `time.getTime()` inside the loop will return the latest time and should fix your problem. Use `getTime()` instead of `getMilliseconds()` because the latter only returns a number between 0 and 999 (ie. less than a second). This limited upper range will be problematic for your code because getMilliseconds() will only return the number of milliseconds elapsed since the previous second.

Comment: I think you correctly diagnosed the problem, but no: calling `getMilliseconds()` does not return the latest time.

Comment: @Bergi Corrected.

Comment: Also the OP must not use `getMilliseconds` but rather `getTime`, or this will fail horrible if the waiting period crosses a second boundary.

Comment: @Bergi I'm learning as much as OP here. Yes, use `getTime` because `getMilliseconds` only returns a number between 0 and 999. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds

Comment: OP here. Thank you so much, this worked. I am running into a new issue where I want to apply the same logic but instead of logging "dark-green" and "light-green" to the console, i would like to change the background color of a div. I've reposted the question here: and was wondering if anyone had some input as to how I could achieve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47892293/change-div-background-color-for-one-second-then-return-it-to-the-original-color

Comment: If that solved your problem please click the big checkbox to accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can you generator as lazy evaluating. Please see below example. To run an infinite loop setInterval. You can modify the code according to your use.

> This is supported on es6 supported browser and node 8.9.1LTS or above.

```
function* asyncRandomNumbers() {
  let tm = new Date().getTime();
  while (true) {
    let updatedTm = new Date().getTime()
    if(updatedTm - tm >= 1000){
      tm = updatedTm;
      yield tm;
    }
  }
}
for (var val of asyncRandomNumbers()) {
  console.log(val) // outputs 0 — 9
}
```