# Change div background color for one second then return it to the original color in javacsript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change the background color of a div for one second then return it back to the original color. I am making a Simon game and can't figure out how to flash a color for a period of time. So far I have this:

```
var red = document.getElementById("redBox");

flashRed();

function flashRed() {
  red.style.background = "#ff0000"; //light red "flash" color
  wait(800);
  red.style.background = "#a80000"; //normal red color
}

function wait(ms) {
  var time = new Date();
  var millisecs = time.getTime();
  var startTime = millisecs;
  var currentTime = millisecs;
  while(currentTime - startTime < ms) {
  time = new Date();
  currentTime = time.getTime();
  }
}
```

How would I go by flashing the bright red for 800ms and then returning the color back to red?

Comment: There is no `wait` in javascript. Use `setTimeout()` and handle asynchronicity.

Comment: I added exmaple in my answer but in general jQuery is good idea for such tasks. It rly depends on what you do but still check jQuery animate and other helper functions

Comment: @Griva JQuery is in no way needed for such a simple task. JQuery is habitually overused.

Comment: for single one - yes, thats why I said depends what he do.

Comment: @Griva this is for a class exercise in which we cannot use jQuery.

Comment: understand, then you got your answer multiple time then :) anyway JS works in one thread so there are no such things like wait because this would freeze whole browser, if you want to do something after some time you have to wait X time or check it in setInterval every X time. Remeber that timout functions don't run callbacks exactly after 1000ms, it try to do it in time but it can be 1500ms for exmaple if some other task is performed very long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use setTimeout() function. It fires some callback after selected time, for example

```
setTimeout(function(){
     // some code
},1000); // for 1s = 1000ms
```

You can add class in setTimeout function so your CSS can change background.

Here is working example: [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dwz1ac50/)

In short, first of all your element need some initial styles and when you want to change color or something else you just add another class with some properties - red backgorund in this example but at the same time you set timeout to remove it later but not stopping your whole code.

Comment: I have tried this but so far all I am able to do is change the color from one shade of red to another, but I am not able to return it to the original color. How can I achieve this return to the original color with setTimeout?

Comment: Thank you Griva, this works well. My next issue is that I need to change the background color of 4 different objects in a certain sequence. How can I do this by calling the function that changes the color of the background whenever I want?

Comment: This should be separated question. You need to add more details, it can be done by firing another timeout from the first one or just calling at the same time 4 of them but with different time, first one 1s, next one 2s and so on

Comment: Okay I will make another question.

Comment: if you wanted to get answer for whole question you should add it from the beggining and avoid asking question1 and then making question2,3,4 in comments this is not how stack works i think. by the way you should mark aswers with checkmarks if it wokrs for you, i seen you asked some questions but you don't checkmark answers

Comment: I am new to stack and do not know how it works. Thank you for letting me know I will be sure to do this.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the way to go about this. Instead use timers via **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)**:

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div");
var originalColor = getComputedStyle(div).backgroundColor; // Store original color (red)

div.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0";  // Change color

// Set a timer to run the passed function after 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
setTimeout(function(){
  div.style.backgroundColor = originalColor;  // Change the color back to the original
}, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red; /* This is the original color */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: The problem here is that I want to do this for four separate divs with separate colors, in a certain sequence. That's why I went about it the way I did, so I can call the function when I want to.

Comment: @MichaelMungai This is the way to do it. There's no reason you can't extend this solution to four colors being "played" in a certain sequence. You just fire off the timers one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
< script type = "text/javascript" > 
toggle_color("#61beb3", "#90a2c6", 4000, 2000);

function toggle_color(color1, color2, cycle_time, wait_time) {

    setInterval(function first_color() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color1;
        setTimeout(change_color, wait_time);
    }, cycle_time);

    function change_color() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color2;
    }
} < /script>
```

The Javascript code above will simply toggle the background color of HTML body once every 2 seconds.  You should use setTimeout() function. It fires some callback after selected time. The color #61beb3 will remain as background until #90a2c6 is set as background by change_color() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use the CSS transition technique, for example:-

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
 div {
    transition: 2s;
 }
div:hover {
 background:red;
}
</style>
</head>
 <body>

 <h1>The transition Property</h1>

 <p>Hover over the div element below, to see the transition effect:</p>
 <div>My Box</div>

</body>
```

So I did for hovering the element you can apply the css using Javascript also.